# How can I insert result from stored procedure to a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure that returns a `SELECT` (can't convert it into a view because it does a little bit more than a `SELECT`). I want to store the results into a new non temporary table.

So far this is what I've tried

```
select * 
into newTable 
from (StoredProcedure) t
```

But it throws an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

EDIT: My SP is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Soporte.ManejoSPs
@NombreSP nvarchar (200)
AS

declare @qry nvarchar (500)

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = @NombreSP + 'Table')
BEGIN

    set @qry = 'select top 0 into ' + @NombreSP  + 'Table from (@NombreSP)     t'
    print @qry
    exec(@qry)
END


declare @Ultima datetime
declare @Tabla nvarchar(200)
declare @Minutos int

Select @Minutos = Minutos, @Tabla = NombreTabla, @Ultima = UltimaVez from     Soporte.ManejoSP where NombreSP = @NombreSP

If (datediff(mi, @Ultima, getdate()) > @Minutos)
BEGIN

    set @qry = 'INSERT INTO ' + @Tabla + ' exec ' + @NombreSP
    exec(@qry)
END

set @qry = 'Select * from ' + @Tabla
exec(@qry)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note*: The following will only work up until SQL Server 2008 R2. For SQL Server 2012+ this will not work (requires `WITH RESULT SETS`, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) for some details on its specification).

---

If your stored procedure is called `t` (in database `db_name` and schema `schema_name`) and the table `newTable` doesn't exist yet:

```
SELECT
  *
INTO
  newTable
FROM
  OPENROWSET (
    'SQLNCLI',
    'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
    'SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC [db_name].[schema_name].t;'
  );
```

If the server is a named instance, you need to supply the proper Server parameter (`ServerName\Instance`).

For this to work, you need the execute following first to allow `Ad Hoc Distributed Queries`. You only need to execute this once.

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

---

If the `newTable` table already exists:

```
INSERT INTO newTable
EXEC t
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am looking for something more generic. This would be inside another SP which will be used pretty often and in different servers, so I would prefer to not change the query everytime I would be implementing this in a different server.

Comment: @Gonza Then you should really be more specific in your question. What exactly is the use-case you need a solution for? Edit your question and describe as detailed as possible. GL.

Comment: how is `INSERT INTO newTable EXEC t` less generic than `select * into newTable from (StoredProcedure) t`?

Comment: @DanBracuk That would work perfectly if I had the table previously created, but I don't. I don't know which or how many columns will it have. Each time could be different. This is why I need to automatically create this new table

Comment: @Gonza You can do that using the first statement I gave you. It will create the table `newTable` as part of the statement.

Comment: @TT Yes, but in that statement I have to manually set the server which is what I am trying to avoid because this would be running in different servers.

Comment: @Gonza It would be running on different servers. But on each of those servers, that server can be addressed by `localhost`. Perhaps you should try it out?

Comment: @TT ok, thanks for the suggestion. Gonna try it out later. Thanks again

Comment: @Gonza You can also try `OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;','EXEC t')` that should work as well. GL.

Comment: @TT Hi mate, I tried using your first statement, but I keep getting this error

    Cannot process the object "EXEC t". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

Comment: @Gonza Using `Trusted_Connection=yes` uses Windows Authentication to connect to the SQL Server. Verify that this account has sufficient rights to execute stored procedures (or specifically, stored procedure `t`).

Comment: @TT I already tried Truste_Connection=yes or providing the credentials (this login has admin rights) but neither seems to work. Also tried with SQLOLEDB as provider and adding the environment settings SET FMTONLY OFF; and SET NOCOUNT ON; but it keeps returning the same error

Comment: @Gonza In executing the stored procedure, supply the database name, the schema and the stored procedure name. Like `EXEC DBNAME.dbo.t` for instance. Sometimes starting with `SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC DBNAME.dbo.t;` is needed (I've had to do that once as well). It's all cumbersome eh?

Comment: YES! You were right! I was missing the DBNAME before the schema. Thank you so much